# Violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I have an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc8pT.png)
Script i try ro run:
[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkV6K.png)
Nginx config generated by CSP generator:
[nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSJpy.png)

I trired generate script by CSP, its not working
i tried also :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Authenticated</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
</head>

<body>
  Authenticated successfully.

  <script>
    window.opener.postMessage({
      token: '<%= jwtToken %>',
      ok: true
    }, '<%= clientUrl %>');
    window.close();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please give me any suggestions because i can't handle this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are adding CSP in both meta tag and header. The content will need to pass all policies to be allowed. The CSP in the error message doesn't match any of the policies you have shown. You have either taken samples from different times or there is yet another policy. Check the response headers to see if there are other policies present.

You are inserting dynamic values into an inline script. In this situation the hash of the script will change every time, so you either have to calculate the hash to be inserted in your CSP, use nonce, or use 'unsafe-inline' (in which case CSP has reduced effect).